# How to get information from map using mouseover?

Tags: plotting, visualization, geography, dynamic

Assume I have the following zip code data:

```
SCzip = {"01029", "01029", "01029", "01230", "01262", "01453", 
  "01460", "01516", "01545", "01545", "01564", "01583", "01592", 
  "01600", "01720", "01730", "01742", "01748", "01770", "01776", 
  "01776", "01798", "01810", "01810", "01827", "01835", "01845", 
  "01863", "01864", "01887", "01890", "01908", "01929", "01938", 
  "01945", "01945", "01945", "01982", "02043", "02043", "02043", 
  "02043", "02052", "02072", "02109", "02114", "02114", "02116", 
  "02116", "02118", "02144", "02184", "02186", "02186", "02269", 
  "02302", "02455", "02455", "02465", "02474", "02481", "02536", 
  "02557", "02703", "02760", "02806", "02842", "02860", "02871", 
  "02879", "02891", "02911", "02917", "03032", "03053", "03053", 
  "03055", "03063", "03063", "03076", "03264", "03431", "03462", 
  "03748", "03841", "03841", "03841", "03841", "03841", "03842", 
  "03842", "04071", "04401", "04660", "04915", "05450", "05450", 
  "05450", "05450", "05450", "05482", "05482"}
```

Duplicate values are fine, it is part of what I want to calculate. How many times a zip code appears in the list.

Then I get the counties and create a map of the counties, where the shading indicates how many times a zip code was on the list.

```
SCcounty = ZIPCodeData[SCzip, "Counties"];
temp = Table[SCcounty[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, 102}]
GeoRegionValuePlot[Counts[temp]]
```

Which should produce the plot below.

My question is: **Is there a way to use the MouseOver (or other function) so that if I hover my mouse over a part of the map, it will show me relevant information, such as County name?**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with `GeoLabels`:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[Counts[temp], GeoLabels -> (Tooltip[#1, #2] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Works great...such a simple solution. I looked up how Tooltip works, but I'm not sure I understand the meaning of #1, #2 and the & symbol. I guess, that's a more generic Mathematica question.

Comment: @tau1777 Yes, you can find info on this if you look up Slot and Function.

Comment: Cool, Thanks again.